# Java implementation of time to words conversion (RoR's distance_of_time_in_words and time_ago_in_words)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

Do you know if it exists a java implementation of distance_of_time_in_words and time_ago_in_words?

For those who don't know, these methods return a human readable description of the time interval between two dates or between a date and now.

By example:

- 3 days
- A week ago
- 2 minutes ago
- More than a year ago

Comment: The same question with more answers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at http://code.google.com/p/prettytime/?