# How to calculate "time ago" in Java?

Tags: java, date, time, datediff, relative-time-span

In Ruby on Rails, there is a feature that allows you to take any Date and print out how "long ago" it was.

For example:

```
8 minutes ago
8 hours ago
8 days ago
8 months ago
8 years ago
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Java?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time It is C#, but I'm sure you can convert it with little trouble.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Take a look at the [PrettyTime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library.

It's quite simple to use:

```
import org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime;

PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
// prints "moments ago"
```

You can also pass in a locale for internationalized messages:

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime(new Locale("fr"));
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
// prints "à l'instant"
```

As noted in the comments, Android has this functionality built into the [`android.text.format.DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long%29) class.

Comment: In case you are working on android you can use this: android.text.format.DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString()

Comment: Can you please add some more description to your answer, link only answer is not good for now.

Comment: @Somatik if you need to get this on a non-android platform, you can [view that class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/format/DateUtils.java) on AOSP.

Comment: @ataylor how this use in Android ??

Comment: getRelativeTimeSpanString is not ideal for all situations and that is why I created my own class based on lots of the examples here. See my solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37042254/468360

Comment: I'm using this library to get ago time in this timestamp : "2016-09-24 09:57:12 AM", But this returns "9 Months Ago". (Current time is : 2016-09-24 10:53 AM). 
`PrettyTime pt = new PrettyTime(new Locale("en"));
            System.out.print(pt.format(date_format.parse("2016-09-24 09:57:12 AM")));` Working on simple EE project with glassfish server. @ataylor

Comment: I always get times in the future, like "1 hour from now" when the time passed is actually before.

Comment: for something so simple there is no point of using a library, can just make one util class inside

Answer (score 73):

Have you considered the [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum? It can be pretty useful for this kind of thing

```
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date past = format.parse("01/10/2010");
        Date now = new Date();

        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " milliseconds ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " minutes ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " hours ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " days ago");
    }
    catch (Exception j){
        j.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a complete answer since the time units are independent. E.g - the milliseconds time is just minutes time * 60 * 1000. You need to decrease from each time unit that next bigger time unit(after converting it to the lower time unit) in order to be able to use it in a "time ago" string.

Comment: **@Benj** - Does it right ? above solution ? because one time is in 12 hour format and another time is in 24 hour format. Let me know your feedback for my query. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: this is incorrect though... each unit is independent of eachother like already mentioned.

Comment: android does it for you In case you are working on android you can use this: android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(milliseconds)

Answer (score 59):

I take RealHowTo and Ben J answers and make my own version:

```
public class TimeAgo {
public static final List<Long> times = Arrays.asList(
        TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(365),
        TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30),
        TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),
        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1),
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1),
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1) );
public static final List<String> timesString = Arrays.asList("year","month","day","hour","minute","second");

public static String toDuration(long duration) {

    StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i< TimeAgo.times.size(); i++) {
        Long current = TimeAgo.times.get(i);
        long temp = duration/current;
        if(temp>0) {
            res.append(temp).append(" ").append( TimeAgo.timesString.get(i) ).append(temp != 1 ? "s" : "").append(" ago");
            break;
        }
    }
    if("".equals(res.toString()))
        return "0 seconds ago";
    else
        return res.toString();
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(toDuration(123));
    System.out.println(toDuration(1230));
    System.out.println(toDuration(12300));
    System.out.println(toDuration(123000));
    System.out.println(toDuration(1230000));
    System.out.println(toDuration(12300000));
    System.out.println(toDuration(123000000));
    System.out.println(toDuration(1230000000));
    System.out.println(toDuration(12300000000L));
    System.out.println(toDuration(123000000000L));
}}
```

which will print the following

```
0 second ago
1 second ago
12 seconds ago
2 minutes ago
20 minutes ago
3 hours ago
1 day ago
14 days ago
4 months ago
3 years ago
```

Comment: Really cool. And it is really easy to add other time units such as week(s)

Comment: this one deserves more upvotes. First of all, no library needed. It's still clean, elegant and easy to change.

Comment: small typo: inside your code your are referencing the static properties "Lists" instead of "TimeAgo". Lists.times.get(i) should be TimeAgo.get(i)... and so on

Comment: Static variable name typo fixed.

Comment: @RiccardoCasatta I entered DateTime in this format `2016-06-07 07:20:33`, it always return 16days ago, why?

Comment: The function take a parameter which is a time delta expressed in millisecond. You should pass differences between dates not a date alone. You are probably passing a timestamp (which is second from 1970) to the function.

Comment: Little suggestion: use `.append(temp != 1 ? "s" : "")` instead of `.append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")` because 0 should also have `s` suffix

Comment: Nice solution, very easy to modify if you'd like other text like "Yesterday" or  adapt so it can give periods relative to a future date ie "In 3 weeks"

Comment: Is `toDuration` method taking the duration parameter as milliseconds? If Yes, then passing 1502531374441 is returning 47 years ago to me but it is my current time.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal yes, the duration parameter is in millisecond but it's a difference between times not an absolute value. What you are getting is the time which has passed from the 1st of January 1970 the date when the unix timestamp started

Comment: Thanks A TON for this.

Comment: In case you are working on android you can use this: android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(milliseconds)

Answer (score 45):

```
  public class TimeUtils {
    
      public final static long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
      public final static long SECONDS = 60;
    
      public final static long ONE_MINUTE = ONE_SECOND * 60;
      public final static long MINUTES = 60;
      
      public final static long ONE_HOUR = ONE_MINUTE * 60;
      public final static long HOURS = 24;
      
      public final static long ONE_DAY = ONE_HOUR * 24;
    
      private TimeUtils() {
      }
    
      /**
       * converts time (in milliseconds) to human-readable format
       *  "<w> days, <x> hours, <y> minutes and (z) seconds"
       */
      public static String millisToLongDHMS(long duration) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        long temp = 0;
        if (duration >= ONE_SECOND) {
          temp = duration / ONE_DAY;
          if (temp > 0) {
            duration -= temp * ONE_DAY;
            res.append(temp).append(" day").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")
               .append(duration >= ONE_MINUTE ? ", " : "");
          }
    
          temp = duration / ONE_HOUR;
          if (temp > 0) {
            duration -= temp * ONE_HOUR;
            res.append(temp).append(" hour").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")
               .append(duration >= ONE_MINUTE ? ", " : "");
          }
    
          temp = duration / ONE_MINUTE;
          if (temp > 0) {
            duration -= temp * ONE_MINUTE;
            res.append(temp).append(" minute").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "");
          }
    
          if (!res.toString().equals("") && duration >= ONE_SECOND) {
            res.append(" and ");
          }
    
          temp = duration / ONE_SECOND;
          if (temp > 0) {
            res.append(temp).append(" second").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "");
          }
          return res.toString();
        } else {
          return "0 second";
        }
      }
    
   
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(123));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS((5 * ONE_SECOND) + 123));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(ONE_DAY + ONE_HOUR));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(ONE_DAY + 2 * ONE_SECOND));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(ONE_DAY + ONE_HOUR + (2 * ONE_MINUTE)));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS((4 * ONE_DAY) + (3 * ONE_HOUR)
            + (2 * ONE_MINUTE) + ONE_SECOND));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS((5 * ONE_DAY) + (4 * ONE_HOUR)
            + ONE_MINUTE + (23 * ONE_SECOND) + 123));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(42 * ONE_DAY));
        /*
          output :
                0 second
                5 seconds
                1 day, 1 hour
                1 day and 2 seconds
                1 day, 1 hour, 2 minutes
                4 days, 3 hours, 2 minutes and 1 second
                5 days, 4 hours, 1 minute and 23 seconds
                42 days
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a revised version of this.  Posted my revisions for you.

Comment: David Blevins, more examples about PrettyTime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java Big -1 for reinventing the wheel once more and not recommending a 3rd party library :-p

Answer (score 11):

This is based on RealHowTo's answer so if you like it, give him/her some love too.

This cleaned up version allows you to specify the range of time you might be interested in.

It also handles the " and " part a little differently.  I often find when joining strings with a delimiter it's ofter easier to skip the complicated logic and just delete the last delimiter when you're done.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

public class TimeUtils {

    /**
     * Converts time to a human readable format within the specified range
     *
     * @param duration the time in milliseconds to be converted
     * @param max      the highest time unit of interest
     * @param min      the lowest time unit of interest
     */
    public static String formatMillis(long duration, TimeUnit max, TimeUnit min) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

        TimeUnit current = max;

        while (duration > 0) {
            long temp = current.convert(duration, MILLISECONDS);

            if (temp > 0) {
                duration -= current.toMillis(temp);
                res.append(temp).append(" ").append(current.name().toLowerCase());
                if (temp < 2) res.deleteCharAt(res.length() - 1);
                res.append(", ");
            }

            if (current == min) break;

            current = TimeUnit.values()[current.ordinal() - 1];
        }

        // clean up our formatting....

        // we never got a hit, the time is lower than we care about
        if (res.lastIndexOf(", ") < 0) return "0 " + min.name().toLowerCase();

        // yank trailing  ", "
        res.deleteCharAt(res.length() - 2);

        //  convert last ", " to " and"
        int i = res.lastIndexOf(", ");
        if (i > 0) {
            res.deleteCharAt(i);
            res.insert(i, " and");
        }

        return res.toString();
    }
}
```

Little code to give it a whirl:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long[] durations = new long[]{
            123,
            SECONDS.toMillis(5) + 123,
            DAYS.toMillis(1) + HOURS.toMillis(1),
            DAYS.toMillis(1) + SECONDS.toMillis(2),
            DAYS.toMillis(1) + HOURS.toMillis(1) + MINUTES.toMillis(2),
            DAYS.toMillis(4) + HOURS.toMillis(3) + MINUTES.toMillis(2) + SECONDS.toMillis(1),
            DAYS.toMillis(5) + HOURS.toMillis(4) + MINUTES.toMillis(1) + SECONDS.toMillis(23) + 123,
            DAYS.toMillis(42)
        };

        for (long duration : durations) {
            System.out.println(TimeUtils.formatMillis(duration, DAYS, SECONDS));
        }

        System.out.println("\nAgain in only hours and minutes\n");

        for (long duration : durations) {
            System.out.println(TimeUtils.formatMillis(duration, HOURS, MINUTES));
        }
    }

}
```

Which will output the following:

```
0 seconds
5 seconds 
1 day and 1 hour 
1 day and 2 seconds 
1 day, 1 hour and 2 minutes 
4 days, 3 hours, 2 minutes and 1 second 
5 days, 4 hours, 1 minute and 23 seconds 
42 days 

Again in only hours and minutes

0 minutes
0 minutes
25 hours 
24 hours 
25 hours and 2 minutes 
99 hours and 2 minutes 
124 hours and 1 minute 
1008 hours
```

And in case anyone ever needs it, here's a class that will convert any string like the above [back into milliseconds](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openejb/trunk/openejb3/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/util/Duration.java). It's pretty useful for allowing people to specify timeouts of various things in readable text.

Answer (score 10):

there's a simple way to do this:

let's say you want the time 20 minutes ago:

```
Long minutesAgo = new Long(20);
Date date = new Date();
Date dateIn_X_MinAgo = new Date (date.getTime() - minutesAgo*60*1000);
```

that's it..

Comment: In most cases, you want a "smart" display, ie. instead of 5125 minutes ago, you tell x days ago.

Answer (score 9):

**About *built-in* solutions:**

Java does not have any built-in support for formatting relative times, also not Java-8 and its new package `java.time`. If you only need English and nothing else then and only then a hand-made solution might be acceptable - see the answer of @RealHowTo (although it has the strong disadvantage to not take into account the timezone for the translation of instant deltas to local time units!). Anyway, if you want to avoid home-grown complex workarounds especially for other locales then you need an external library.

In latter case, I recommend to use my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (or Time4A on Android). It offers **greatest flexibility and most i18n-power**. The class [net.time4j.PrettyTime](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html) has seven methods `printRelativeTime...(...)` for this purpose. Example using a test clock as time source:

```
TimeSource<?> clock = () -> PlainTimestamp.of(2015, 8, 1, 10, 24, 5).atUTC();
Moment moment = PlainTimestamp.of(2015, 8, 1, 17, 0).atUTC(); // our input
String durationInDays =
  PrettyTime.of(Locale.GERMAN).withReferenceClock(clock).printRelative(
    moment,
    Timezone.of(EUROPE.BERLIN),
    TimeUnit.DAYS); // controlling the precision
System.out.println(durationInDays); // heute (german word for today)
```

Another example using `java.time.Instant` as input:

```
String relativeTime = 
  PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH)
    .printRelativeInStdTimezone(Moment.from(Instant.EPOCH));
System.out.println(relativeTime); // 45 years ago
```

This library supports via its latest version (v4.17) **80 languages** and also some country-specific locales (especially for Spanish, English, Arabic, French). The i18n-data is mainly based on the **newest CLDR-version v29**. Other important reasons why to use this library are good **support for plural rules** (which are often different from English in other locales), **abbreviated format style** (for example: "1 sec ago") and expressive ways for **taking into account timezones**. Time4J is even aware of such exotic details like **leap seconds** in calculations of relative times (not really important but it forms a message related to the expectation horizon). The **compatibility with Java-8** exists due to easily available conversion methods for types like `java.time.Instant` or `java.time.Period`.

Are there any drawbacks? Only two.

- The library is not small (also because of its big i18n-data repository).
- The API is not well known so community knowledge and support are not available yet otherwise the supplied documentation is pretty detailed and comprehensive.

**(Compact) alternatives:**

If you look for a smaller solution and don't need so many features and are willing to tolerate possible quality issues related to i18n-data then:

- I would recommend **ocpsoft/PrettyTime** (support for actually 32 languages (soon 34?) suitable for work with `java.util.Date` only - see the answer of @ataylor). The industry standard CLDR (from Unicode consortium) with its big community background is unfortunately not a base of the i18n-data so further enhancements or improvements of data can take a while...
- If you are on Android then the helper class **android.text.format.DateUtils** is a slim built-in alternative (see other comments and answers here, with the disadvantage that it has no support for years and months. And I am sure that only very few people like the API-style of this helper class.
- If you are a fan of **Joda-Time** then you can look at its class [PeriodFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormat.html#wordBased(java.util.Locale)) (support for 14 languages in release v2.9.4, on the other side: Joda-Time is surely not compact, too, so I mention it here just for completeness). This library is not a real answer because relative times are not supported at all. You will need to append the literal " ago" at least (and manually stripping off all lower units from generated list formats - awkward). Unlike Time4J or Android-DateUtils, it has no special support for abbreviations or automatic switching from relative times to absolute time representations. Like PrettyTime, it is totally dependent on the unconfirmed contributions of private members of the Java-community to its i18n-data.

Answer (score 8):

## *java.time*

The [Answer by Habsq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964523/642706) has the right idea but the wrong methods.

For a span-of-time unattached to the timeline on the scale of years-months-days, use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html). For days meaning 24-hour chunks of time unrelated to calendar and hours-minutes-seconds, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). Mixing the two scales rarely makes any sense.

## `Duration`

Start by fetching the current moment as seen in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), using the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
Instant then = now.minus( 8L , ChronoUnit.HOURS ).minus( 8L , ChronoUnit.MINUTES ).minus( 8L , ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
Duration d = Duration.between( then , now );
```

Generate text for hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
// Generate text by calling `to…Part` methods.
String output = d.toHoursPart() + " hours ago\n" + d.toMinutesPart() + " minutes ago\n" + d.toSecondsPart() + " seconds ago";
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "From: " + then + " to: " + now );
System.out.println( output );
```

> From: 2019-06-04T11:53:55.714965Z to: 2019-06-04T20:02:03.714965Z

> 8 hours ago

> 8 minutes ago

> 8 seconds ago

## `Period`

Start by getting the current date.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true-time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Recreate a date eight days, months, and years ago.

```
LocalDate then = today.minusYears( 8 ).minusMonths( 8 ).minusDays( 7 ); // Notice the 7 days, not 8, because of granularity of months.
```

Calculate elapsed time.

```
Period p = Period.between( then , today );
```

Build the string of "time ago" pieces.

```
String output = p.getDays() + " days ago\n" + p.getMonths() + " months ago\n" + p.getYears() + " years ago";
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "From: " + then + " to: " + today );
System.out.println( output );
```

> From: 2010-09-27 to: 2019-06-04

> 8 days ago

> 8 months ago

> 8 years ago

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a good answer--rather than adding my own I'll just +1 and mention here that Duration has a "Parse" method that lets you specify values more easily, like "P2D" is 2 days, "P2D2M" is 2 days and 2 minutes.   This gives a straight-forward Instance.now().minus(Duraiton.parse("P2H")) for "2 Hours Ago"

Answer (score 6):

## java.time

Using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

```
LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime t2 = LocalDateTime.now();
Period period = Period.between(t1.toLocalDate(), t2.toLocalDate());
Duration duration = Duration.between(t1, t2);

System.out.println("First January 2015 is " + period.getYears() + " years ago");
System.out.println("First January 2015 is " + period.getMonths() + " months ago");
System.out.println("First January 2015 is " + period.getDays() + " days ago");
System.out.println("First January 2015 is " + duration.toHours() + " hours ago");
System.out.println("First January 2015 is " + duration.toMinutes() + " minutes ago");
```

Comment: Those `Duration` methods report the *entire* duration as a total number of hours and as a total number of minutes. In Java 8 the class oddly lacked any methods to get each *part* of hour and minutes and seconds. Java 9 brings those methods, `to…Part`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on a bunch of answers here, I created the following for my use case.

Example usage:

```
String relativeDate = String.valueOf(
                TimeUtils.getRelativeTime( 1000L * myTimeInMillis() ));
```

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.DAYS;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.HOURS;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

/**
 * Utilities for dealing with dates and times
 */
public class TimeUtils {

    public static final List<Long> times = Arrays.asList(
        DAYS.toMillis(365),
        DAYS.toMillis(30),
        DAYS.toMillis(7),
        DAYS.toMillis(1),
        HOURS.toMillis(1),
        MINUTES.toMillis(1),
        SECONDS.toMillis(1)
    );

    public static final List<String> timesString = Arrays.asList(
        "yr", "mo", "wk", "day", "hr", "min", "sec"
    );

    /**
     * Get relative time ago for date
     *
     * NOTE:
     *  if (duration > WEEK_IN_MILLIS) getRelativeTimeSpanString prints the date.
     *
     * ALT:
     *  return getRelativeTimeSpanString(date, now, SECOND_IN_MILLIS, FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
     *
     * @param date String.valueOf(TimeUtils.getRelativeTime(1000L * Date/Time in Millis)
     * @return relative time
     */
    public static CharSequence getRelativeTime(final long date) {
        return toDuration( Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - date) );
    }

    private static String toDuration(long duration) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i< times.size(); i++) {
            Long current = times.get(i);
            long temp = duration / current;
            if (temp > 0) {
                sb.append(temp)
                  .append(" ")
                  .append(timesString.get(i))
                  .append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")
                  .append(" ago");
                break;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString().isEmpty() ? "now" : sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very useful, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

If you looking for a simple "Today", "Yesterday" or "x days ago".

```
private String getDaysAgo(Date date){
    long days = (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime()) / 86400000;

    if(days == 0) return "Today";
    else if(days == 1) return "Yesterday";
    else return days + " days ago";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## For Android:

```
public static String getTimeAgoFormat(long timestamp) {
    return android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple [Java timeago](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/java-timeago) port of the [jquery-timeago](http://rmm5t.github.com/jquery-timeago/) plug-in that does what you are asking for.

```
TimeAgo time = new TimeAgo();
String minutes = time.timeAgo(System.currentTimeMillis() - (15*60*1000)); // returns "15 minutes ago"
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you're developing an app for Android, it provides the utility class [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) for all such requirements. Take a look at the [DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long)) utility method.

From the docs for

***CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpanString (long time, long now, long minResolution)***

> Returns a string describing 'time' as a time relative to 'now'. Time spans in the past are formatted like "42 minutes ago". Time spans in the future are formatted like "In 42 minutes".

You'll be passing your `timestamp` as *time* and `System.currentTimeMillis()` as *now*. The `minResolution` lets you specify the minimum timespan to report.

> For example, a time 3 seconds in the past will be reported as "0 minutes ago" if this is set to MINUTE_IN_MILLIS. Pass one of 0, MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, HOUR_IN_MILLIS, DAY_IN_MILLIS, WEEK_IN_MILLIS etc.

Answer (score 3):

The [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) package, has the notion of [Periods](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html). You can do arithmetic with Periods and  DateTimes.

From the [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
public boolean isRentalOverdue(DateTime datetimeRented) {
  Period rentalPeriod = new  Period().withDays(2).withHours(12);
  return datetimeRented.plus(rentalPeriod).isBeforeNow();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You Can use this function to calculate time ago

```
 private String timeAgo(long time_ago) {
        long cur_time = (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
        long time_elapsed = cur_time - time_ago;
        long seconds = time_elapsed;
        int minutes = Math.round(time_elapsed / 60);
        int hours = Math.round(time_elapsed / 3600);
        int days = Math.round(time_elapsed / 86400);
        int weeks = Math.round(time_elapsed / 604800);
        int months = Math.round(time_elapsed / 2600640);
        int years = Math.round(time_elapsed / 31207680);

        // Seconds
        if (seconds <= 60) {
            return "just now";
        }
        //Minutes
        else if (minutes <= 60) {
            if (minutes == 1) {
                return "one minute ago";
            } else {
                return minutes + " minutes ago";
            }
        }
        //Hours
        else if (hours <= 24) {
            if (hours == 1) {
                return "an hour ago";
            } else {
                return hours + " hrs ago";
            }
        }
        //Days
        else if (days <= 7) {
            if (days == 1) {
                return "yesterday";
            } else {
                return days + " days ago";
            }
        }
        //Weeks
        else if (weeks <= 4.3) {
            if (weeks == 1) {
                return "a week ago";
            } else {
                return weeks + " weeks ago";
            }
        }
        //Months
        else if (months <= 12) {
            if (months == 1) {
                return "a month ago";
            } else {
                return months + " months ago";
            }
        }
        //Years
        else {
            if (years == 1) {
                return "one year ago";
            } else {
                return years + " years ago";
            }
        }
    }
```

1) Here time_ago is in microsecond

Answer (score 3):

```
private const val SECOND_MILLIS = 1
private const val MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS
private const val HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS
private const val DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS

object TimeAgo {

fun timeAgo(time: Int): String {

    val now = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis())
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        return "in the future"
    }

    val diff = now - time
    return when {
        diff < MINUTE_MILLIS -> "Just now"
        diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> "a minute ago"
        diff < 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> "${diff / MINUTE_MILLIS} minutes ago"
        diff < 2 * HOUR_MILLIS -> "an hour ago"
        diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS -> "${diff / HOUR_MILLIS} hours ago"
        diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS -> "yesterday"
        else -> "${diff / DAY_MILLIS} days ago"
    }
}
```

}

Call

val String = timeAgo(unixTimeStamp)

to get the time ago in Kotlin

Comment: accuracy for yesterday should be based on day factor, since 48 hours can be between 3 days and things done on day 1 will be labeled as yesterday which in reality is day 3 or (3 days ago).

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty...but the closest I can think of is using Joda-Time (as described in this post: [How to calculate elapsed time from now with Joda Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time)

Answer (score 2):

This is a better code if we consider performance.It reduces the number of calculations.
**Reason**
Minutes are calculated only if the number of seconds is greater than 60 and Hours are calculated only if the number of minutes is greater than  60 and so on...

```
class timeAgo {

static String getTimeAgo(long time_ago) {
    time_ago=time_ago/1000;
    long cur_time = (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())/1000 ;
    long time_elapsed = cur_time - time_ago;
    long seconds = time_elapsed;
   // Seconds
    if (seconds <= 60) {
        return "Just now";
    }
    //Minutes
    else{
        int minutes = Math.round(time_elapsed / 60);

        if (minutes <= 60) {
            if (minutes == 1) {
                return "a minute ago";
            } else {
                return minutes + " minutes ago";
            }
        }
        //Hours
        else {
            int hours = Math.round(time_elapsed / 3600);
            if (hours <= 24) {
                if (hours == 1) {
                    return "An hour ago";
                } else {
                    return hours + " hrs ago";
                }
            }
            //Days
            else {
                int days = Math.round(time_elapsed / 86400);
                if (days <= 7) {
                    if (days == 1) {
                        return "Yesterday";
                    } else {
                        return days + " days ago";
                    }
                }
                //Weeks
                else {
                    int weeks = Math.round(time_elapsed / 604800);
                    if (weeks <= 4.3) {
                        if (weeks == 1) {
                            return "A week ago";
                        } else {
                            return weeks + " weeks ago";
                        }
                    }
                    //Months
                    else {
                        int months = Math.round(time_elapsed / 2600640);
                        if (months <= 12) {
                            if (months == 1) {
                                return "A month ago";
                            } else {
                                return months + " months ago";
                            }
                        }
                        //Years
                        else {
                            int years = Math.round(time_elapsed / 31207680);
                            if (years == 1) {
                                return "One year ago";
                            } else {
                                return years + " years ago";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: In case you are working on android you can use this: android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(milliseconds)

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) which are modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and were introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

1. Use `Duration` to calculate a time-based quantity or amount of time. It can be accessed using duration-based units, such as nanoseconds, seconds, minutes and hours. In addition, the [DAYS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS) unit can be used and is treated as exactly equal to 24 hours, thus ignoring daylight savings effects.
2. Use `Period` to calculate a date-based amount of time. It can be accessed using period-based units, such as days, months and years.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An arbitrary local date and time
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.DECEMBER, 10, 15, 20, 25);

        // Current local date and time
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds, %d nanoseconds ago",
                duration.toDays(), duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60,
                duration.toNanos() % 1000000000);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds, %d nanoseconds ago",
                duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart(),
                duration.toNanosPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT1395H35M7.355288S
58 days, 3 hours, 35 minutes, 7 seconds, 355288000 nanoseconds ago
58 days, 3 hours, 35 minutes, 7 seconds, 355288000 nanoseconds ago
```

If you have two moments at `UTC`, you can use `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime` e.g.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Current moment at UTC
        Instant now = Instant.now();

        // An instant in the past
        Instant startDateTime = now.minus(58, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
                                .minus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS)
                                .minus(54, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
                                .minus(24, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
                                .minus(808624000, ChronoUnit.NANOS);

        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, now);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds, %d nanoseconds ago",
                duration.toDays(), duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60,
                duration.toNanos() % 1000000000);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds, %d nanoseconds ago",
                duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart(),
                duration.toNanosPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT1394H54M24.808624S
58 days, 2 hours, 54 minutes, 24 seconds, 808624000 nanoseconds ago
58 days, 2 hours, 54 minutes, 24 seconds, 808624000 nanoseconds ago
```

**Demo on `Period`:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable timezone ID e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("Europe/London"). For LocalDate in the JVM's timezone, simply use
        // LocalDate.now()
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        // Let's assume the start date is 1 year, 2 months, and 3 days ago
        LocalDate startDate = endDate.minusYears(1).minusMonths(2).minusDays(3);

        Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(period);

        // Custom format
        String formattedElapsedPeriod = String.format("%d years, %d months, %d days ago", period.getYears(),
                period.getMonths(), period.getDays());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedPeriod);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
P1Y2M3D
1 years, 2 months, 3 days ago
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 1):

After long research i found this.

```
    public class GetTimeLapse {
    public static String getlongtoago(long createdAt) {
        DateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
        DateFormat dateFormatNeeded = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
        Date date = null;
        date = new Date(createdAt);
        String crdate1 = dateFormatNeeded.format(date);

        // Date Calculation
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        crdate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);

        // get current date time with Calendar()
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currenttime = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

        Date CreatedAt = null;
        Date current = null;
        try {
            CreatedAt = dateFormat.parse(crdate1);
            current = dateFormat.parse(currenttime);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get msec from each, and subtract.
        long diff = current.getTime() - CreatedAt.getTime();
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        String time = null;
        if (diffDays > 0) {
            if (diffDays == 1) {
                time = diffDays + "day ago ";
            } else {
                time = diffDays + "days ago ";
            }
        } else {
            if (diffHours > 0) {
                if (diffHours == 1) {
                    time = diffHours + "hr ago";
                } else {
                    time = diffHours + "hrs ago";
                }
            } else {
                if (diffMinutes > 0) {
                    if (diffMinutes == 1) {
                        time = diffMinutes + "min ago";
                    } else {
                        time = diffMinutes + "mins ago";
                    }
                } else {
                    if (diffSeconds > 0) {
                        time = diffSeconds + "secs ago";
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Android**
Exactly like Ravi said, but since lots of people want to **just copy-paste** the thing here it is.

```
  try {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
      Date dt = formatter.parse(date_from_server);
      CharSequence output = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString (dt.getTime());
      your_textview.setText(output.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      your_textview.setText("");
    }
```

**Explanation for people that have more time**

1. You get the data from somewhere. First, you have to figure out its format.

Ex. I get the data from a server in the format
Wed, 27 Jan 2016 09:32:35 GMT [this is probably NOT your case]

this is translated into

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

how do I know it? Read the [documentation here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Then after I parse it I get a date. that date I put in the getRelativeTimeSpanString (without any additional parameters is fine by me, to default to minutes)

**You WILL get an exception** if you didn't figure out the **correct parsing String**, Something like exception **at character 5**. **Look at character 5, and correct your initial parsing string.**. You might get another exception, repeat these steps until you have the correct formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's Library [RelativeDateTimeFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/RelativeDateTimeFormatter), it does exactly that:

```
RelativeDateTimeFormatter fmt = RelativeDateTimeFormatter.getInstance();
 fmt.format(1, Direction.NEXT, RelativeUnit.DAYS); // "in 1 day"
 fmt.format(3, Direction.NEXT, RelativeUnit.DAYS); // "in 3 days"
 fmt.format(3.2, Direction.LAST, RelativeUnit.YEARS); // "3.2 years ago"

 fmt.format(Direction.LAST, AbsoluteUnit.SUNDAY); // "last Sunday"
 fmt.format(Direction.THIS, AbsoluteUnit.SUNDAY); // "this Sunday"
 fmt.format(Direction.NEXT, AbsoluteUnit.SUNDAY); // "next Sunday"
 fmt.format(Direction.PLAIN, AbsoluteUnit.SUNDAY); // "Sunday"

 fmt.format(Direction.LAST, AbsoluteUnit.DAY); // "yesterday"
 fmt.format(Direction.THIS, AbsoluteUnit.DAY); // "today"
 fmt.format(Direction.NEXT, AbsoluteUnit.DAY); // "tomorrow"

 fmt.format(Direction.PLAIN, AbsoluteUnit.NOW); // "now"
```

Comment: That's an Android library, not a Java library.

Answer (score 1):

SQL timestamp to now elapsed time. Set your own timezone.

NOTE1: This will handle singular/plural.

NOTE2: This is using Joda time

```
String getElapsedTime(String strMysqlTimestamp) {
    
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    DateTime mysqlDate = formatter.parseDateTime(strMysqlTimestamp).
                         withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"));
    
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    Period period = new Period(mysqlDate, now);
    
    int seconds = period.getSeconds();
    int minutes = period.getMinutes();
    int hours = period.getHours();
    int days = period.getDays();
    int weeks = period.getWeeks();
    int months = period.getMonths();
    int years = period.getYears();
    
    String elapsedTime = "";
    if (years != 0)
        if (years == 1)
            elapsedTime = years + " year ago";
        else
            elapsedTime = years + " years ago";
    else if (months != 0)
        if (months == 1)
            elapsedTime = months + " month ago";
        else
            elapsedTime = months + " months ago";
    else if (weeks != 0)
        if (weeks == 1)
            elapsedTime = weeks + " week ago";
        else
            elapsedTime = weeks + " weeks ago";
    else if (days != 0)
        if (days == 1)
            elapsedTime = days + " day ago";
        else
            elapsedTime = days + " days ago";
    else if (hours != 0)
        if (hours == 1)
            elapsedTime = hours + " hour ago";
        else
            elapsedTime = hours + " hours ago";
    else if (minutes != 0)
        if (minutes == 1)
            elapsedTime = minutes + " minute ago";
        else
            elapsedTime = minutes + " minutes ago";
    else if (seconds != 0)
        if (seconds == 1)
            elapsedTime = seconds + " second ago";
        else
            elapsedTime = seconds + " seconds ago";   
    
    return elapsedTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Java Implementation of this

```
    public static String relativeDate(Date date){
    Date now=new Date();
    if(date.before(now)){
    int days_passed=(int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - date.getTime());
    if(days_passed>1)return days_passed+" days ago";
    else{
        int hours_passed=(int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - date.getTime());
        if(hours_passed>1)return days_passed+" hours ago";
        else{
            int minutes_passed=(int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - date.getTime());
            if(minutes_passed>1)return minutes_passed+" minutes ago";
            else{
                int seconds_passed=(int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - date.getTime());
                return seconds_passed +" seconds ago";
            }
        }
    }

    }
    else
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy").format(date).toString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
public class TimeDifference {
    int years;
    int months;
    int days;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    String differenceString;

    public TimeDifference(@NonNull Date curdate, @NonNull Date olddate) {

        float diff = curdate.getTime() - olddate.getTime();
        if (diff >= 0) {
            int yearDiff = Math.round((diff / (AppConstant.aLong * AppConstant.aFloat)) >= 1 ? (diff / (AppConstant.aLong * AppConstant.aFloat)) : 0);
            if (yearDiff > 0) {
                years = yearDiff;
                setDifferenceString(years + (years == 1 ? " year" : " years") + " ago");
            } else {
                int monthDiff = Math.round((diff / AppConstant.aFloat) >= 1 ? (diff / AppConstant.aFloat) : 0);
                if (monthDiff > 0) {
                    if (monthDiff > AppConstant.ELEVEN) {
                        monthDiff = AppConstant.ELEVEN;
                    }
                    months = monthDiff;
                    setDifferenceString(months + (months == 1 ? " month" : " months") + " ago");
                } else {
                    int dayDiff = Math.round((diff / (AppConstant.bFloat)) >= 1 ? (diff / (AppConstant.bFloat)) : 0);
                    if (dayDiff > 0) {
                        days = dayDiff;
                        if (days == AppConstant.THIRTY) {
                            days = AppConstant.TWENTYNINE;
                        }
                        setDifferenceString(days + (days == 1 ? " day" : " days") + " ago");
                    } else {
                        int hourDiff = Math.round((diff / (AppConstant.cFloat)) >= 1 ? (diff / (AppConstant.cFloat)) : 0);
                        if (hourDiff > 0) {
                            hours = hourDiff;
                            setDifferenceString(hours + (hours == 1 ? " hour" : " hours") + " ago");
                        } else {
                            int minuteDiff = Math.round((diff / (AppConstant.dFloat)) >= 1 ? (diff / (AppConstant.dFloat)) : 0);
                            if (minuteDiff > 0) {
                                minutes = minuteDiff;
                                setDifferenceString(minutes + (minutes == 1 ? " minute" : " minutes") + " ago");
                            } else {
                                int secondDiff = Math.round((diff / (AppConstant.eFloat)) >= 1 ? (diff / (AppConstant.eFloat)) : 0);
                                if (secondDiff > 0) {
                                    seconds = secondDiff;
                                } else {
                                    seconds = 1;
                                }
                                setDifferenceString(seconds + (seconds == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") + " ago");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        } else {
            setDifferenceString("Just now");
        }

    }

    public String getDifferenceString() {
        return differenceString;
    }

    public void setDifferenceString(String differenceString) {
        this.differenceString = differenceString;
    }

    public int getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public void setYears(int years) {
        this.years = years;
    }

    public int getMonths() {
        return months;
    }

    public void setMonths(int months) {
        this.months = months;
    }

    public int getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(int days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the very basic script. its easy to improvized.
Result : (XXX Hours Ago), or (XX Days Ago/Yesterday/Today)

```
<span id='hourpost'></span>
,or
<span id='daypost'></span>

<script>
var postTime = new Date('2017/6/9 00:01'); 
var now = new Date();
var difference = now.getTime() - postTime.getTime();
var minutes = Math.round(difference/60000);
var hours = Math.round(minutes/60);
var days = Math.round(hours/24);

var result;
if (days < 1) {
result = "Today";
} else if (days < 2) {
result = "Yesterday";
} else {
result = days + " Days ago";
}

document.getElementById("hourpost").innerHTML = hours + "Hours Ago" ;
document.getElementById("daypost").innerHTML = result ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this I've done `Just Now, seconds ago, min ago, hrs ago, days ago, weeks ago, months ago, years ago` in this example you can parse date like `2018-09-05T06:40:46.183Z` this or any other like below

add below value in **string.xml**

```
  <string name="lbl_justnow">Just Now</string>
    <string name="lbl_seconds_ago">seconds ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_min_ago">min ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_mins_ago">mins ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_hr_ago">hr ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_hrs_ago">hrs ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_day_ago">day ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_days_ago">days ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_lstweek_ago">last week</string>
    <string name="lbl_week_ago">weeks ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_onemonth_ago">1 month ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_month_ago">months ago</string>
    <string name="lbl_oneyear_ago" >last year</string>
    <string name="lbl_year_ago" >years ago</string>
```

java code try below

```
  public String getFormatDate(String postTime1) {
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now=cal.getTime();
        String disTime="";
        try {
            Date postTime;
            //2018-09-05T06:40:46.183Z
            postTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(postTime1);

            long diff=(now.getTime()-postTime.getTime()+18000)/1000;

            //for months
            Calendar calObj = Calendar.getInstance();
            calObj.setTime(postTime);
            int m=calObj.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            calObj.setTime(now);

            SimpleDateFormat monthFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM"); // output month

            int mNow = Integer.parseInt(monthFormatter.format(postTime));

            diff = diff-19800;

            if(diff<15) { //below 15 sec

                disTime = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_justnow);
            } else if(diff<60) {

                //below 1 min
                disTime= diff+" "+getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_seconds_ago);
            } else if(diff<3600) {//below 1 hr

                // convert min
                long temp=diff/60;

                if(temp==1) {
                    disTime= temp + " " +getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_min_ago);
                } else {
                    disTime = temp  + " " +getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_mins_ago);
                }
            } else if(diff<(24*3600)) {// below 1 day

                // convert hr
                long temp= diff/3600;
                System.out.println("hey temp3:"+temp);
                if(temp==1) {
                    disTime = temp  + " " +getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_hr_ago);
                } else {
                    disTime = temp + " " +getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_hrs_ago);
                }
            } else if(diff<(24*3600*7)) {// below week

                // convert days
                long temp=diff/(3600*24);
                if (temp==1) {
                    //  disTime = "\nyesterday";
                    disTime = temp + " " +getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_day_ago);
                } else {
                    disTime = temp + " " +getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_days_ago);
                }
            } else if(diff<((24*3600*28))) {// below month

                // convert week
                long temp=diff/(3600*24*7);
                if (temp <= 4) {

                    if (temp < 1) {
                        disTime = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_lstweek_ago);
                    }else{
                        disTime = temp + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_week_ago);
                    }

                } else {
                    int diffMonth = mNow - m;
                    Log.e("count : ", String.valueOf(diffMonth));
                    disTime = diffMonth + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_month_ago);
                }
            }else if(diff<((24*3600*365))) {// below year

                // convert month
                long temp=diff/(3600*24*30);

                System.out.println("hey temp2:"+temp);
                if (temp <= 12) {

                    if (temp == 1) {
                        disTime = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_onemonth_ago);
                    }else{
                        disTime = temp + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_month_ago);
                    }
                }

            }else if(diff>((24*3600*365))) { // above year

                // convert year
                long temp=diff/(3600*24*30*12);

                System.out.println("hey temp8:"+temp);

                if (temp == 1) {
                    disTime = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_oneyear_ago);
                }else{
                    disTime = temp + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_year_ago);
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return disTime;
    }
```

Comment: In case you are working on android you can use this: android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Instant, Date and DateTimeUtils.
The data (date) which is stored in the database in type of String and then convert to become Instant.

```
    /*
    This method is to display ago.
    Example: 3 minutes ago.
    I already implement the latest which is including the Instant.
    Convert from String to Instant and then parse to Date.
     */
    public String convertTimeToAgo(String dataDate) {
    //Initialize
    String conversionTime = null;
    String suffix = "Yang Lalu";
    Date pastTime;
    //Parse from String (which is stored as Instant.now().toString()
    //And then convert to become Date
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(dataDate);
    pastTime = DateTimeUtils.toDate(instant);

    //Today date
    Date nowTime = new Date();

    long dateDiff = nowTime.getTime() - pastTime.getTime();
    long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dateDiff);
    long minute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dateDiff);
    long hour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dateDiff);
    long day = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dateDiff);

    if (second < 60) {
        conversionTime = second + " Saat " + suffix;
    } else if (minute < 60) {
        conversionTime = minute + " Minit " + suffix;
    } else if (hour < 24) {
        conversionTime = hour + " Jam " + suffix;
    } else if (day >= 7) {
        if (day > 30) {
            conversionTime = (day / 30) + " Bulan " + suffix;
        } else if (day > 360) {
            conversionTime = (day / 360) + " Tahun " + suffix;
        } else {
            conversionTime = (day / 7) + " Minggu " + suffix;
        }
    } else if (day < 7) {
        conversionTime = day + " Hari " + suffix;
    }
    return conversionTime;
    }
```

Comment: You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque I still cannot find the latest way to do this.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've added some code for me to understand it. https://github.com/ticherhaz/tarikhmasa

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions are all in pure Java:

### Option 1: No rounding and only largest time container

The following function will only display the largest time container, for example, if the true elapsed time is `"1 month 14 days ago"`, this function will only display `"1 month ago"`. This function will also always round down, so a time equivalent to `"50 days ago"` will display as `"1 month"`

```java
public String formatTimeAgo(long millis) {
        String[] ids = new String[]{"second","minute","hour","day","month","year"};

        long seconds = millis / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = minutes / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;
        long months = days / 30;
        long years = months / 12;

        ArrayList<Long> times = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds));

        for(int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++) {
            if(times.get(i) != 0) {
                long value = times.get(i).intValue();

                return value + " " + ids[ids.length - 1 - i] + (value == 1 ? "" : "s") + " ago";
            }
        }

        return "0 seconds ago";
    }
```

### Option 2: With rounding

Simply wrap the time container you'd like to round with a Math.round(...) statement, so if you wanted to round `50 days` to `2 months`, modify `long months = days / 30` to `long months = Math.round(days / 30.0)`

Comment: Using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) with its `to…Part` methods would be much easier, as shown in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56450659/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test case, hope it helps:

```
    val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    currentCalendar.set(2019, 6, 2, 5, 31, 0)

    val targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    targetCalendar.set(2019, 6, 2, 5, 30, 0)

    val diffTs = currentCalendar.timeInMillis - targetCalendar.timeInMillis
    val diffMins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffTs)
    val diffHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffTs)
    val diffDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffTs)
    val diffWeeks = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffTs) / 7
    val diffMonths = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffTs) / 30
    val diffYears = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffTs) / 365

    val newTs = when {
        diffYears >= 1 -> "Years $diffYears"
        diffMonths >= 1 -> "Months $diffMonths"
        diffWeeks >= 1 -> "Weeks $diffWeeks"
        diffDays >= 1 -> "Days $diffDays"
        diffHours >= 1 -> "Hours $diffHours"
        diffMins >= 1 -> "Mins $diffMins"
        else -> "now"
    }
```

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Poor advice in 2019.

Comment: You must have meant `var`, not `val`.

Answer (score 0):

The *getrelativeDateTime* function will give you date time as you see in Whatsapp notification.
To get future relative Date Time add conditions for it. This is created specifically for getting Date Time like Whatsapp notification.

```
private static String getRelativeDateTime(long date) {
    SimpleDateFormat DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat TimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
    long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    long startOfDay = StartOfDay(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    String Day = "";
    String Time = "";
    long millSecInADay = 86400000;
    long oneHour = millSecInADay / 24;
    long differenceFromNow = now - date;

    if (date > startOfDay) {
        if (differenceFromNow < (oneHour)) {
            int minute = (int) (differenceFromNow / (60000));
            if (minute == 0) {
                int sec = (int) differenceFromNow / 1000;
                if (sec == 0) {
                    Time = "Just Now";
                } else if (sec == 1) {
                    Time = sec + " second ago";
                } else {
                    Time = sec + " seconds ago";
                }
            } else if (minute == 1) {
                Time = minute + " minute ago";
            } else if (minute < 60) {
                Time = minute + " minutes ago";
            }
        } else {
            Day = "Today, ";
        }
    } else if (date > (startOfDay - millSecInADay)) {
        Day = "Yesterday, ";
    } else if (date > (startOfDay - millSecInADay * 7)) {
        int days = (int) (differenceFromNow / millSecInADay);
        Day = days + " Days ago, ";
    } else {
        Day = DateFormat.format(date);
    }
    if (Time.isEmpty()) {
        Time = TimeFormat.format(date);
    }
    return Day + Time;
}

public static long StartOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. It's not exactly what was asked, but maybe someone can use it. Neither that someone nor anyone else should want to use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`, though. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead read the answers that are employing java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 0):

For the lack of simplicity and updated response, follows the more recent Java 8 and beyond version

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

public class Time {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(LocalTime.now().minus(8, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
        System.out.println(LocalTime.now().minus(8, ChronoUnit.HOURS));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().minus(8, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().minus(8, ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
    }
}
```

*This is the version that uses the Java Time API that tries to solve issues from the past for dealing with Date and Time.*

Javadoc

**version 8**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html

**version 11**
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html

W3Schools Tutorial - https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_date.asp

DZone Article - https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-date-and-time