# Parsing date times in "X minutes/hours/days/weeks/months/years ago" format

Tags: java

How can parse dates that are in the format like X minutes/hours/days/weeks/months/years ago. Here are some examples to show what I'm referring to:

- 3 days ago
- 1 minute ago
- 2 years ago

I don't think is is easily possible with the default Java libraries. Am I right?

Comment: Are you planning to parse "3 days and 2 hours ago"?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for PrettyTime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java

Comment: Hi Aioobe, No, I'm not. Just the simple format as I've shown.

Comment: @aioobe apologies for my stupidity, I'm going to go wash my eyes out in bleach :P

Comment: Android's DateUtil class can handle this, [source code here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/format/DateUtils.java).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little snippet based on the `Calendar` API.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(.*?)s? ago");

Map<String, Integer> fields = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("second", Calendar.SECOND);
    put("minute", Calendar.MINUTE);
    put("hour",   Calendar.HOUR);
    put("day",    Calendar.DATE);
    put("week",   Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    put("month",  Calendar.MONTH);
    put("year",   Calendar.YEAR);
}};

String[] tests = {
        "3 days ago",
        "1 minute ago",
        "2 years ago"
};

for (String test : tests) {

    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    if (m.matches()) {
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        String unit = m.group(2);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(fields.get(unit), -amount);
        System.out.printf("%s: %tF, %<tT%n", test, cal);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3 days ago: 2012-08-18, 09:21:38
1 minute ago: 2012-08-21, 09:20:38
2 years ago: 2010-08-21, 09:21:38
```

Comment: Thanks Aioobe. Your solution works great. Upvote. BTW, do you know a library that can do this too?

Comment: I ran into a little issue with this. I suggest replacing the space with a `\\s`.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on a context you are referring 'ago', is it from current date, or from specified date.

You can achieve it using Java APIs:

- tokenize string into three parts using [Java Regex API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)
- create and manipulate dates using [Java Calendar API](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html)