# Fancy time-formatter displaying "5 min ago", "yesterday" etc

Tags: java, time, datetime-format

What is the best way to format time like modern web-pages (including StackOverflow ;-) do, i.e. using simple relative descriptions like:

- 5 seconds ago
- 23 minutes ago
- yesterday
- 2 days ago
- ...

I am looking for a library that can handle this in addition to multiple locales. I can supply the phrases ( *"X seconds"* in English, *"X Sekunden"* in German etc.).

Comment: Tale a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for :

[How to calculate "time ago" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java?rq=1)

The lib: [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

For German:

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime(new Locale("de"));
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
```

For English:

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
```

Apparently available in 25 languages.