# Facebook posts timestamps "X mins ago"

Tags: java, c#, datetime, timestamp

I want to implement in my app date and time standards like facebook does
for example:

```
post from x minust ago shows as: X mins
post from x seconds ago shows as: X secs
.....
post from yesterday shows as: yestarday at 7:22pm
post from last month shows as: june 15 ...
```

I am searching for the full timestamp dictinary that convert's datetime to
string facebook X time ago

Comment: It can't be that hard to implement, surely?

Comment: No it is not !! i just wanted to know the convantion..
1 years ago?
10 years ago? with or without time stamps?

Comment: Fair point. I interpreted as wanting a library recommendation as you wanted something to convert `DateTime` to string. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to calculate "time ago" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java)

> Take a look at the [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/) library.
>
> It's quite simple to use:

```
import org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime;

PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
// prints "moments ago"
```

> You can also pass in a locale for internationalized messages:

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime(new Locale("fr"));
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
// prints "à l'instant"
```

> As noted in the comments, Android has this functionality built into the [`android.text.format.DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long%29) class.