# Dateformat to hours and minutes for Android

Tags: java, date, time

I have a date format as

```
31-07-2015 11:00:50
```

I want to convert it in hours and minutes left from now.ie

```
10h:21m
```

I tried quite a few objects like SimpleFormat,Calendar or Date,but didn't get anywhere. The format I am using is.

```
dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate "time ago" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java)

Comment: @Theo Your example does not make sense. How did you go from a date-time to ten hours and twenty-one minutes? Are you talking about how much time passed? Also, please search StackOverflow before posting. Try terms like "elapsed" and "ISO 8601" and "duration".

Comment: you are looking for remaining time like `12h:59m:10s` if time now `11:00:50`. @Theo