# How would Time Ago function implementation look like in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I mean function, when given time returns smallest time unit ago.
E.g

- "5 minutes ago"
- "30 seconds ago"
- "just now"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible implementation might look like this:

Note, I've used [clj-time/clj-time · GitHub](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) library.

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as t])

(defn time-ago [time]
  (let [units [{:name "second" :limit 60 :in-second 1}
               {:name "minute" :limit 3600 :in-second 60}
               {:name "hour" :limit 86400 :in-second 3600}
               {:name "day" :limit 604800 :in-second 86400}
               {:name "week" :limit 2629743 :in-second 604800}
               {:name "month" :limit 31556926 :in-second 2629743}
               {:name "year" :limit Long/MAX_VALUE :in-second 31556926}]
        diff (t/in-seconds (t/interval time (t/now)))]
    (if (< diff 5)
      "just now"
      (let [unit (first (drop-while #(or (>= diff (:limit %))
                                         (not (:limit %))) 
                                    units))]
        (-> (/ diff (:in-second unit))
            Math/floor
            int
            (#(str % " " (:name unit) (when (> % 1) "s") " ago")))))))
```

Example usage:

```
(time-ago (t/minus (t/now) (t/days 400)))
=> "1 year ago"

(time-ago (t/minus (t/now) (t/days 15)))
=> "2 weeks ago"

(time-ago (t/minus (t/now) (t/seconds 45))) 
=> "45 seconds ago"

(time-ago (t/minus (t/now) (t/seconds 1)))
=> "just now"
```

Comment: What case is the 

(not (:limit %)) 

for?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Clojure on the JVM, consider using the [PrettyTime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library. Using that library for implementing "time ago" in Java was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java).

To use PrettyTime library from Clojure, first add the following to the `:dependencies` vector in project.clj:

```
[org.ocpsoft.prettytime/prettytime "3.2.7.Final"]
```

Then you can use Java interop directly. One quirk I found is that the cut-off between "moments ago" and other outputs is at 1 minute by default. I added a line to change that to one second. This library appears to support several languages, which is a plus. By default it prints "moments ago" instead of "just now". It would require some effort to deal with in case that is really important.

```
(import 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime
       'org.ocpsoft.prettytime.units.JustNow
       'java.util.Date)

(defn time-ago [date]
  (let [pretty-time (PrettyTime.)]
    (.. pretty-time (getUnit JustNow) (setMaxQuantity 1000))
    (.format pretty-time date)))

(let [now (System/currentTimeMillis)]
  (doseq [offset [200, (* 30 1000), (* 5 60 1000)]]
     (println (time-ago (Date. (- now offset))))))

;; moments ago
;; 30 seconds ago
;; 5 minutes ago
```

Answer (score 1):

It only supports minutes, hours & days but if that's sufficient you may also want to look at `goog.date.relative`:

https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/date/relative.js#L87